# How to make Nivo Slider 100% height of the browser?

Tags: css, nivo-slider

I am working on a website using Nivo Slider here: [Website Demo](http://cappatravel.com/)

The problem is, the slider section won't do 100% height following the browser's height. How can I do that?

I have been inspecting and found this css code:

```
.nivoSlider {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  left:0;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

According to my CSS knowledge, we can change the `height:auto;` to `height:100%` to make the slider 100% height. Alas, it does not work!

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

I found that the image of the sliders is taking over the size, which is written here:

```
.nivoSlider img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  max-width: none;
  max-height: 100%; // I ADDED THIS TO MAKE 100% HEIGHT AND IT WORKS!!!
}
```

nevertheless, the image is being stretched now, how can I make the image cut, instead of stretched?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following class. You have assigned `900px` height.

```
.nivoSlider:after {
content: '';
background: transparent url(../../images/parallax_slider/pattern.png) repeat top left;
position: absolute;
height: 900px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that, but I tried and it does not work. I found something though, that is setting the img inside the slider to max-height: 100%; it works but the image is streched now. I am looking for the solution for it.